# Why did Ada in the Resident Evil series come back after dying in Resident Evil 2?

Tags: resident-evil-series, resident-evil-2-1998

The deaths just don't make any sense. Are there any explanations for the bizarre events? (Ada died in two different cutscenes, both different ends, and returned in *RE6*!) (Steve died in *Code Veronica* but returned in *The Darkside Chronicles*!)

Answer (score 1):

Steve died in RE Code Veronica X for sure, but The dark side chronicles is more like a remake or a spin-off of the game; same bosses, same places, etc.

Ada did not die in RE2, as far as I remember after she gets hit I think from William Birkin in that trolley, Leon helps her to rest and goes out to kill one of the most irritating RE bosses ever

P.S.: In Resident Evil Code Veronica X ending, Wesker said "Maybe he'll come back alive just as I did, and to see your sister again". I really wish this become true!